# did not get perfect answer with datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Datediff is very confusing for fetch the difference between two days:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-07')+1) AS totaldays
```

when i write above then it will give me 7 days it is perfect....

but when i write the below

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02')+1) AS totaldays
```

then it will give me 2 days but i want `1 day` with this below function

```
 DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02')+1) AS totaldays
```

how can i get it?

Comment: Please explain the logic that you want.  If the first expression correctly calculates 7, I would expect the second to *correctly*  calculate 2.  Perhaps you should edit your question with more examples of dates and the difference you want to calculate.

Comment: but i want 1 day when i write datediff(day,'2014-09-01','2014-09-01-02')....

Comment: You do get one day with that expression.  It turns to two when you add one to it.

Comment: there are no solution for that?

Comment: Explain your logic, 01 - 07 is 6, u add one so it gives you 7, 01 - 02 is 1 you add 1 = 2. What are you trying to get here? If you want to use few kinds of "datediff" types (with different logic) I suggest using `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Its because of that **+1** in your First `DATEDIFF` its **only 6 days** because of **+1** its **7** days in the second `DATEDIFF` its **1** day only because of **+1** its displaying **2** days

Comment: Why are you do adamant about putting "+1" in that formula??  Of **course** you're going to get 1 more than expected when you have a +1 in your formula!

Answer (score 4):

The `DATEDIFF` function is working as expected.

`DATEDIFF` simply subtracts the second parameter from the third parameter by the specific element specified in the first parameter.

For example, the following query provides four columns... all which subtract the day specified in the second parameter from the day specified in the third:

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-07')+1,  -- Calculation: (7-1)+1  = 7
       DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-07'),    -- Calculation: (7-1)    = 6
       DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02')+1,  -- Calculation: (2-1)+1  = 2
       DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02')     -- Calculation: (2-1)    = 1
```

And the results are as expected:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4
 7   |   6  |  2   |   1
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is the MS documentation for this function.

If you want the function to act differently then you will need to utilize [CASE](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/1MS1120313-Understanding-Case-Expression-in-SQL-Server-with-Example.html) statement.

Answer (score 2):

A "day" has a "duration" (that can be measured in units such as 24 hours)

- That duration commences at 00:00:00 +0000
- When we write a date/time as '2014-09-07' the time is assumed to be
  00:00:00 +0000

so this: **DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-07')**

is measuring a duration between:  "the **start** of 2014-09-01" to "the **start** of 2014-09-07" and; trying to represent this as a set of durations where "S" indicates the start point and "---" is the countable duration.

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7 (day of the month)
S---S---S---S---S---S---S   (time span)
```

Count the number of "---" in that time span (6) [and the number of start points, "S", is 7]

`DATEDIFF()` is measuring "duration" NOT the number of start points

What you need to do is add one day to the higher date instead of adding one to the result, because you are using "start of" not "end of" points of time.

```
                  from          to
                start of     start of
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-08') = 7
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-07') = 6
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-06') = 5
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-05') = 4
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-04') = 3
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-03') = 2
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02') = 1
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-01') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove +1 from your SQL.

Use the following : ***DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-09-01','2014-09-02') AS totaldays***

Due to ***+1*** it was giving wrong output.